# What SQL reporting method can I use to extract data that may be fed to two applications?

Tags: sql-server, database, csv

My company has a front end application for reporting authorizations and another front end application for the claims that were approved for payment regarding the authorizations that were requested.

How do I marry the two sources so my output could provide a CSV of auths and claims so I can review what was paid and what is outstanding

Comment: csv should be considered a last-resort format. there's far better/more reliable ways of encapsulating data for transport. csv will work, but invariably will cause far more pain try to compensate for its inherent limitations/stupidities than you would have suffered from implementing a better format (e.g. xml, json, etc...) in the first place.

Comment: Looks like you might want to search for an [ETL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) tool.

Comment: Do the two front end applications use the same database (back end)?

Comment: No neither of the front end apps sit on the same db

Comment: You can create a solution for this using SSIS which is very easy to handle depending on your criteria please take a look at here https://www.ericzimerman.com/getting-started-with-ssis-creating-your-first-package/

Comment: If both databases are on SQL Server then you could create a [linked server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx) on 1 to the other. And then write a SQL that uses tables on both databases using that link. If both databases are on the same server then you probably won't even have to do that.  select * from [mydatabase1].[dbo].[mytable]